# Div scrolling synchronization : scrolltop return wrong value on Android

Tags: jquery, synchronization, scroll

Usually I am using this code to synchronize 2 divs.

```
$('#right').on('scroll', function () {
    $('#left').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});​
```

It is working very well on PC, but not on my Samsung Galaxy tab ??!!

**EDIT**

After some tests, I have discovered that the `scrolltop` value is not correct: it is not taking into account the smooth scrolling end animation or something like that. Therefore, it is not possible to synchronize 2 divs.

Here is a new fiddle to explain the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/sgcer/156/

Is someone could explained why and how I could fix the problem?
Any comment about tests on others tablets are welcome.

I have tried events like `touchmove`, `touchend`, ... but not luck http://jsfiddle.net/sgcer/146/

And scroll event occurred endless on my tablet : http://jsfiddle.net/sgcer/157/

And I found a potential issue here : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19625

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, it working on Chrome browser app, but not will default browser.